# How to disable keyboard events in Pygame?

Tags: python, input, pygame, keyboard

I'm using pygame inside Blender to get multitouch support.

Unfortunately pygame catches all keyboard input which makes it impossible to use shortcuts in Blender.

Can someone help me to unsubscribe from all keyboard events?

Thank you

Comment: A quick look at the docs brought me to `pygame.event.clear` (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.clear), evidently it removes all events from the queue. I'm not sure if this will solve your issue though

Comment: as I remeber `pygame.event` should have method to filter catched events. EDIT: Maybe try [set_allowed()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.set_allowed)

Comment: I have no idea how you use PyGame but if you use it to display some window then system will send all events only to this window and even if you unsubscribe key events in  PyGame system will NOT sent it to other windows. system sends events only to active window - and at this moment other window may catch keys events only if it registered shortcuts as global/system hotkeys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that i used win32gui to render pygame always on top.
The with the "win32con.SWP_NOACTIVATE" flag, i could force pygame to be inactive and blender to be active.

```
    hwnd = pg.display.get_wm_info()["window"]

    rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    x = rect[0]
    y = rect[1]
    w = rect[2] - x
    h = rect[3] - y

    win32gui.SetWindowLong (hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, win32gui.GetWindowLong (hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE ) | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED )
    win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_TOP, x, y, w, h, win32con.SWP_NOACTIVATE)
```

Comment: you can mark your answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can block specific events. According to the pygame wiki, this will stop pygame from queuing those events, but I can't test if it stops pygame from requesting keyboard input.

`pygame.event.set_blocked([pygame.KEYDOWN, pygame.KEYUP])`